# SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser fails with invalidAnswer though requiresQuestionAndAnswer=false

Tags: c#, .net

## Background

I am working on a RESTful API written in C#/.NET and need to switch between the production database and dev database for testing new API calls. The previous lead developer's API made no sense, so we are replacing the most important parts of it before rebuilding the application from scratch.

## The Goal

I need to switch to the `SqlMembershipProvider` for the dev database server on the fly to test CRUD operations on user accounts.

## The Problem

The MSDN "documentation" says that the [`Membership.CreateUser` method calls `SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.createuser(v=vs.110).aspx), but calling this underlying method directly returns `null` and sets the `status` output to `invalidAnswer`.

## Configuration

I have the connection string and provider definition configured in `Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" connectionString="server=prodblahblah">
    <add name="DevConnString" connectionString="server=devblahblah">
```

...

```
<membership defaultProvider="SQLDBMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="SQLDBMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ConnString" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" ...>
        <add name="DevSQLDBMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DevConnString" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" ...>
```

## Code

Based upon the bits of advice I found scattered across the internets, I came up with and attempted the following:

```
SqlMembershipProvider p = (SqlMembershipProvider)Membership.Providers["DevSQLDBMembershipProvider"];
MembershipCreateStatus status;
string question = "";
string answer = "";
MembershipUser mu = p.CreateUser(username, password, email, question, answer, true, Guid.NewGuid(), out status);
```

## Result

The call returns null and sets the output `status` variable to `invalidAnswer`. This perplexes me because `requiresQuestionAndAnswer` is set to `false` in the configuration, and calling `Membership.CreateUser` results in null values in the `aspnet_Membership` table.

Strangely, I get the same outcome when using `Membership.Providers["SQLDBMembershipProvider"]` instead of `["DevSQLDBMembershipProvider"]`, so there must be some difference between the way that `Membership.CreateUser` and `SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser` handle password questions/answers.

## Small Rant About MSDN "Documentation"

The code example given in the MSDN documentation for [SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.createuser(v=vs.110).aspx) does not even actually show how to use `SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser` -- it instead calls `Membership.CreateUser` and does not mention how to access the non-default providers configured in the Web.config file. The code example in the documentation for a method specifically does not show how to use that method. I think it is fair to say that MSDN has the most infuriatingly unhelpful documentation I have ever seen.

## Question

Why does `Membership.CreateUser` work with empty password question/answer values while `SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser` does not? How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer while writing this question. Since it is difficult to find documentation for this stuff anywhere, I decided to post the question and answer it with my findings.

## The Answer

It turns out that `""` is not accepted while `null` is. An empty string is invalid while a `null` is acceptable. This makes perfect sense to everyone, of course. It is inherently intuitive that an empty string is unacceptable while a null string is acceptable. Obvious.

It is definitely a good thing that Microsoft in their infinite[simal] wisdom decided to not show examples of how to use their code in their code examples. They are professionals, after all, and that is just how documentation works.